# Using Vue mouseover event to set styles on two elements is very laggy. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm relatively new to Vue so I may not be doing this in the most performant way. I have a table of rows created with a v-for loop.  I also have a corresponding list of row titles also created with a v-for loop.  They need to be separate DOM elements to enable fixed header scrolling. When I hover over the row I want to change its color AND the color of the corresponding row title.

So I thought you would be able to do the following with Vue:

1. On mouseover set a data property to the index of the element being hovered over.
2. Bind a class to the elements of interest to change their styles when the index is equal to their index from the v-for loop.

This does work but it results in very slow / laggy code. I have quite a few rows (40) and columns (60) but it isn't an enormous amount.

An abridged version of the code is below:

**Template html**

```
<div class="rowTitle" 
  v-for="(rowName, i) in yAxis.values" :key="i"  
  @mouseover="hover(i)" 
  :class="hoverActive(i)" >{{rowName}}</div>

<div class="row" 
  v-for="(row, i) in rows" :key="i" 
  @mouseover="hover(i)" 
  :class="hoverActive(i)" >{{row}}</div>
```

**Vue object**

```
export default {
  data:()=>(
    {
      rows: rows,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      rowHover: -1,
    }
  ),

  methods:{
    hover(i) {
      this.rowHover = i
    },
    hoverActive(i) {
      return this.rowHover == i ? 'hover' : ''
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest not using the index as the v-for key, since it will cause problems down the line if you have complex objects. For example, if an element of the list is removed, only parts of your objects will be properly synchronized (and you risk losing reactivity).

Comment: If you want to just change style of an hovered element, this can be easily done with css.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  How would you implement the index then? @seblor

Comment: @bravemaster - I want to change the styles of a couple of different elements simultaneously so a simple css :hover pseudo class won't work.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I've made a similar table and run some tests. It's perfectly fine with small data(40x60). However for 100x200 or 400x600 there was a serious lagging. This is because Vue has to redraw all tds when mouseover is triggered. There is no other way, I think. Use `:hover ` if possible.

Comment: @HobbyHacker I don't know the content of `rows` or `yAxis.values`, but if they are arrays of objects, use a property which value is unique to them as key. If they are array of primitives and are different, you can directly use it as key.

Answer (score 0):

The likely answer is that the hover event is firing very frequently, and each time it fires you are forcing vue to re-render. If you could add a debounce the event handler, or even better mark the event handler as passive, it would make a big difference in performance. In this runnable snippet, I'm telling vue to use a passive event modifier (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to tell the browser not to prioritize that event handler over critical processes like rendering.

To be clear, if you can use CSS to solve the problem like a commenter mentioned (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), I strongly advise that as the browser's performance should be excellent with that approach. But sometimes css does not solve everything, so a debounce or a passive event listener might be your next best option. You could also experiment with the "stop" (stop propagation) modifier if additional tuning is required.

```js
const grid = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  grid.push([]);
  for (var j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
    grid[i].push({
      i,
      j
    });
  }
}

Vue.component('aTable', {
  props: ['grid'],
  data() {
    return {
      rowHover: -1
    }
  },
  template: `
 <div class="table">
   <div class="row" v-for="(row, x) in grid">
    <span v-for="cell in row"
          @mouseover.passive="hover(x)"
          :class="hoverActive(x)"
          class="row-cell" 
          >i:{{cell.i}},j:{{cell.j}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
`,
  methods: {
    hover(i) {
      this.rowHover = i
    },
    hoverActive(i) {
      return this.rowHover == i ? 'hover' : ''
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      grid
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.row-cell {
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.row-cell.hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  My table
  <a-table :grid="grid" />
</div>
```